# Append the last value column of a group in dataframe to the grouped dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

For The Example Dataframe:

```
       Date T/F  Amount
0  11/10/03   T       5
1  11/10/03   T       5
2  11/10/03   F       9
3  12/10/03   T       1
4  12/10/03   F       3
5  14/10/03   T       3
```

I want to group by date and get the sum of amount (this bit i know how to do) but I also want to set the T/F value for the group to be whatever the last value in the group is, so to produce something like this:

```
       Date  Amount T/F
0  11/10/03      19   F
1  12/10/03       4   F
2  14/10/03       3   T
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUIC, use `agg`

```
In [417]: df.groupby('Date', as_index=False).agg({'T/F': 'last', 'Amount': 'sum'})
Out[417]:
       Date  Amount T/F
0  11/10/03      19   F
1  12/10/03       4   F
2  14/10/03       3   T
```

Is same as

```
In [433]: df.groupby('Date', as_index=False).agg({'T/F': lambda x: x.iloc[-1], 'Amount': np.sum})
Out[433]:
       Date  Amount T/F
0  11/10/03      19   F
1  12/10/03       4   F
2  14/10/03       3   T
```